# How can I aggregate this SQL table into another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

If i have the data table below:

```
COLUMN 1    COLUMN2
Country1    NULL
Country1    0
Country1    NULL
Country1    0
Country1    NULL
Country1    0
Country1    NULL
Country1    18
Country1    NULL
Country1    12
Country1    NULL
Country1    0
Country1    NULL
Country1    0
Country1    NULL
Country2    0
Country2    NULL
Country2    7
Country2    NULL
Country2    0
Country2    NULL
Country2    0
Country2    NULL
Country2    0
```

Ignoring the rows with second column as NULL, how can I get the following values out of it:

Country1 has 7 values, out of which 5 are zero, 1 is 18 and 1 is 12.
Country2 has 5 values, out of which 4 are zero, 1 is 7

How can I get a table that looks like this?

```
COUNTRY VALUE   PERCENT
Country1    0   71.43 (i.e. 5/7)
Country1    18  14.29 (i.e. 1/7)
Country1    12  14.29 (i.e. 1/7)
Country2    0   80 (i.e. 4/5)
Country2    7   20 (i.e. 1/5)
```

Comment: I'm using SQL server management studio

Comment: "please write my query for me"  ಠ_ಠ

Comment: how can he post any query if he doesn't know where to start ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using simple aggregation and window functions:

```
select country, value,
       cast(count(*) as float) / sum(count(value)) over (partition by country) as ratio
from table t
group by country, value;
```

This gives the third column as a ratio.  You can format it as a percent in various ways, such as by using `str()`.

Comment: I believe this produces the wrong denominator due to the `GROUP BY` clause, need a `SUM()`:
`SUM(count(value)) over (partition by country)`

Comment: Goat CO is correct, if we add SUM, the ratio is correct

Comment: @GoatCO is correct.  Mixing aggregation and window functions is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is structure of the query which will help you:

```
select t1.column1, t1.column2, t1.cnt*100.0/t2.totalcnt
from
(
select column1, column2, count(*) as cnt
from table
where column2 is not null
group by column1, column2
) as t1
inner join
(
select column1, count(*) as totalcnt
from table
where column2 is not null
group by column1
) as t2
on t1.column1=t2.column1
```